# Dlookup in Textbox value is not returning up with matching data from table

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a 1st Textbox named `Txtresult` which has date "03-07-2015" and I have table name "Datetbl".

Table has `Duedate` column which has date and the matching column is `Action` which has comments.

I need to get the matching data comments from table to reflect in 2nd Textbox named `Txtanswer`.

I am trying to apply **`DLookup`** function to get the matching result from table. I'm not sure what is going wrong. My **`Dlookup`** function turns up nothing.

So far this is what I have tried:

```
txtanswer = DLookup("Action", "Datetbl", "Duedate=" & txtresult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```vb
txtanswer = Nz(DLookup("Action", "Datetbl", "Duedate= #" & txtresult) & "#","")
```

Notice the `#` around `txtresult` since it is a date.  Additionally the `Nz()` function is to handle the situation where their is no results and prevents an "Invalid Use of Null" error message.